# Silverite Dragon Age Inquisition?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I am playing as a Mage and collected the 8 pieces of silverite needed for the metal on some armor that is meant for rogues but when I make it, it will not allow me to equip it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You might want to mention that silverite is supposed to make armor not bound to a class. Also, what crafting items are you using in what slot?

Answer (score 4):

NOTE:  When crafting there are multiple slots you have to fill.  The middle slot of any item: Referred to as the "armor" slot for armor or "Damage" slot for weapons is the slot that determines the basis of the item being made.  The rest of the slots are additional functionality slots allowing better stats or abilities on the item.  In the information below, ONLY the "Armor" slot matters.  You cannot remove class restrictions on weapons.

1) Every pattern requires a specific type of material to make.  Light armor patterns require "Cloth" type materials in their "Armor" slot.  Medium armor patterns require "Leather" type materials in their "Armor" slot, and Heavy patterns require "Metal" type materials in their "Armor" slot.  A "Light" pattern will NEVER have "Leather" as the "Armor" slot material, and same with all others.  DO NOT GET CONFUSED: Crafted items have many slots, and other than the "Armor" slot (the slot in the middle of the pattern just below the "Masterwork" slot if it appears), the other slots on any given piece of equipment (whether light, medium or heavy) could be Cloth, Leather or Metal (many "Heavy" armors will require leather or cloth in their "utility" or "defense" slots, etc.)

1) Silverite removes restrictions on heavy armor only.  It must go in the "Armor" (main) slot of the armor, meaning only heavy armor.  If you're trying to create medium armor, you are required to put leather in the main (middle) slot...silverite won't fit and thus you can't remove restriction on medium armor with Silverite.  Also, Silverite in any other location (such as defense or utility slots) does not remove class restrictions.

2) Fade Touched Silverite does not make a difference and does not provide a benefit outside of it's masterwork ability (+5 guard on hit).  You DO NOT need fade touched Silverite to make non-class restricted armor.

3) The three "Remove class restrictions" materials are:

- Dales Loden Wool - Used with light armor patterns to allow Medium/Heavy classes to wear it.
- Snoufleur Skin - Used with Medium Armor patterns to allow Light/Heavy classes to wear it.
- Silverite - Used with Heavy Armor patterns to allow Light/Medium classes to wear it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use the Silverite in the Main slot. Also make sure the rogue armor doesn't have a race restriction such as human or elf only. Silverite only removes class not race.

Answer (score 0):

Silverite makes Warrior only armor in restricted. Each type of armor (light, medium, and heavy) requires a different material. I believe for medium armor it is snofleur (spelling may be wrong) leather.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You're a Mage not a Rogue.

Comment: Silverite is supposed to make armor not bound to a specific class, but the question should be edited to make this more obvious.